# grep to find specific results in a text file around | regular expressions?

Tags: linux, grep, expression

I'm having trouble understanding some regular expressions. I'm trying search a specific field between 2 pipe characters  in a text file such as

```
|nope|target|tree|
|target|nope|nah|
```

What kind of regular expression with grep would I use to only return the first line? More specifically only find "target" when its in the second field

Comment: This is definitely a job for awk, not grep. With grep it's impossible to simply match a string within a field as grep needs to use REs to find the field and it can't do both an RE match and a string match in the same command line. See @Kent's answer.

Answer (score 2):

print the line that 2nd field is target:

```
kent$  echo "|nope|target|tree|
|target|nope|nah|"|awk -F'|' '$3=="target"'
|nope|target|tree|
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit unclear, but I guess you want something like this:

```
grep '|.*|target|.*|' my_file.txt
```

Comment: that would match 'target' in any field after the first and before the last, not just in the 2nd. I know the sample only had 3 fields but I wouldn't assume 3-field files is literally the only case the OP is asking about. It also has the problem that it's matching target as an RE, not a string, see the comment I posted by @steve's answer.

Comment: Sure, but that depends on the input format specification. It's also insufficient if the input field may contain escaped pipe symbols. If the OP isn't more specific about the format, there is no way of knowning how much caution is required when writing the regex. Also, I don't understand you other comment: The pipe symbol is not escaped, so grep takes it as a normal character to match.

Comment: I'm not sure which comment is you're referring to at the end there, but if it's about RE vs string, it's not the pipe symbol that's very problematic being treated as an RE, its the text within the field.

Comment: @EdMorton: I don't understand, the text matches just fine. Please provide an explanation or a link, otherwise this looks like you are just spreading FUD.

Comment: I've no idea what FUD means but try searching for the specific STRING "tar.et" in your input file and notice that grep incorrectly matches on "target" because it's doing an RE comparison, not a string comparison.To match on a string with grep you'd need to use fgrep but then you can't use an RE to describe the lead field(s) to be skipped so you're stuck between a rock and a hard place.

Comment: In which case you'd just use "tar\.et" in your regex, problem solved. You claim that there is a fundamental problem and REs can't be used for the task. That is just plain wrong and thus you are spreading FUD = Fear,Uncertainty,Doubt.

Comment: That does NOT solve the problem. It provides a workaround for one specific case. To solve the full problem you'd have to write/use a tool that understands REs and can determine which RE metacharacters in your target string are being used as such in that string and which aren't and then escape them as appropriate. You can't even just escape all RE metacharacters because whether you can/should do that or not depends on the context in which they're used (e.g. `[]]` has `]` in 2 different contexts). Seriously - think a bit about how you'd do this and you'll see why you shouldn't even attempt it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24630/discussion-between-daniel-frey-and-ed-morton)

Comment: Sorry I really don't have anything to add and I've spent far too much time on it already. If you want to use grep for this, feel free.

Answer (score 0):

To match the second field:

```
grep "^|[^|]*|target|" file
```

Results:

```
|nope|target|tree|
```

Explanation:

```
^          # match start of line
|          # a pipe symbol
[^|]*      # anything not a pipe symbol any number of times
|          # a pipe symbol
target     # the word 'target'
|          # a pipe symbol
```

Comment: It's not the word 'target' being matched, it's the regular expression 'target'. It matters if you want to match, say "a.com" and the file contains "a.com" but also "abcom". Note that the above as written would also falsely match 'targeting'.

Comment: @EdMorton: Oh the trailing pipe... Done. It's all regexp. That should be obvious.

Comment: that'd work for this particular case but in general you'd have to make it `([|]|$)` in case the targeted field is the last one on the line and then you'd have to switch to egrep and escape the other pipe symbols. You'd also need to throw in a {N} after the first RE segment surrounded in () to skip N leading fields for the general case and then you STILL have the problem that you're matching an RE not a string within the targeted field. It all just becomes a bit pointless trying to make grep work when it's just not meant for the job and it's trivial in awk.

Comment: @EdMorton: I totally agree. Kent's answer should be accepted one. He just beat me to it. Added the `grep` solution in case the OP was interested. Who knows?